# C - Freeing data structures in threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, data-structures

I just finished creating a LinkedList in C and I have a `clear` function.

The clear function iterates through the LinkedList and calls `free()` on each Node. This means it's an `O(n)` function, quite slow.

Should I instead create a `pthread` (or some other thread library which I don't know about), provide it my `root` Node, set my LinkedList's `root` Node to NULL, then have the thread clean up the memory while the list is now ready to be added to right away? Is there danger in doing this? It would mean that the user can add more data to the LinkedList before there is necessarily enough space to account for it right? It's like a credit card but for memory.

Is it safe to do this? What would make for robust and speedy code for this type of situation?

Comment: "... quite slow." - compared to what? Sure, memory leaking as you seem to think about is often faster. Said that: not clear what you are asking. Provide a [mcve] with all required information.

Comment: Linked lists typically perform poorly, and not because of deallocation. Without a benchmark, a reference machine and the performance requirements this question is not answerable.

Comment: In my opinion this is the only way to clear the whole linked list . "set my LinkedList's root Node to NULL, then have the thread clean up the memory" if you loose your `root` node how can you access to the other nodes ?

Comment: @Olaf If I use a `thread` to clear the LinkedList then the main thread which may be using the LinkedList as say... a queue won't have to wait for the O(n) operation. Meaning, you could add `n` elements to the LinkedList, call `clear` (which is O(n)) and your main thread never has to loop over the main List. It saves an extra cycle of `O(n)`

Comment: @Mouin I would pass the `root`Node to the garbage cleaning thread but in the LinkedList `struct` I would set `root` to `NULL`, that way operations like `insert`, `size`, etc will all presume the LinkedList is empty.

Comment: Unless you have profiled your application and determined that freeing a linked list is an unacceptable performance bottleneck, you have no business trying to optimise it. Much less optimise it using technology you have very vague ideas about and zero experience with. Now if you want to learn about multithreading, you can of course, but parallelising linked list operations is not a very good introductory task.

Comment: @n.m. Three things. Firstly I don't think it's right to tell someone not to try something because it's too hard. It's not good advice to learners especially here on StackOverflow. Second, it was simply a question of 'in the most optimal sense, **should** a (insert data structure name here)'s `clear` function be put onto a different thread'; yes or no. Thirdly, I use my LinkedList file for all of my projects as no standard library data structures are provided for me. I have to make it all myself. So if I want a fast queue, I have to code one that way.

Comment: No, running a linked list clear operation in a thread is not hard. It's trivial and teaches you nothing. It is also most likely useless. No, running a clear operation of any data structure in a separate thread is not beneficial 99% of the time, though nobody can guarantee your particular application is not in the 1%. You need to experiment and verify it by yourself. No, you shouldn't use linked lists in general, they perform poorly except in very few very special circumstances.

Comment: Think about `clear` in the sense of a HashMap. Only 75% of the HashMap's buckets are occupied so you have to loop over the entire array (size of `capacity`). Then you ALSO have to loop inside each bucket which is `O(n)` worse case. This operation is quite expensive and could be easily performed in a thread. I don't see why you wouldn't unless there is problems with thread safety. Also, LinkedLists are excellent queues and stacks. A LinkedList never has to grow like an array  does. A queue only adds and removes which is what LinkedLists are supreme at.

Comment: First, if you are replying to someone specific, use the @ convention like this @Hatefiend. Next, no, linked lists are at most mediocre stacks and queues. Don't believe me, measure for yourself. Yes, you can do this stuff in a thread. No, this rarely makes sense unless you are running a light application on an unloaded machine (which would just mean you overspecified your machine). Normally all threads are already saturated. Threads make sense when you can run them while waiting for I/O, this can improve your latency. Anyway, if you are so inclined to use threads, go ahead, don't ask me.

Comment: In general, measure the performance, then start improving it. The order of these actions is not optional. In my experience linked lists are inferior in almost any situation and freeing a data structure won't benefit from running in its own thread, but who knows what happens with your application in your environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136746/discussion-between-n-m-and-hatefiend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you compile with pthreads, then free should be threadsafe.

Is it safe? Use a mutex to make sure that the access is protected from concurrent edits.

Should you do it? It is considered bad architectural style to hide threads behind common container structures. Your library users will consider clear() a blocking method that gets the job done. If a library user needs asynchronous free, he can fork a thread on his own.

Does a linked list clear has to have O(n) time complexity? Not really if all memory is in a managed continuous block.

Comment: I was about to write an answer prior to yours being written. I will only add that he will not gain speed but an overhead due to creating threads, waiting for lock and so on... ends up as a single unit of execution even though there are 2 threads or more.

Comment: The question is more of, SHOULD I use threads to clear out the memory of ANY data structure or should I just use the thread I'm on and clear them in O(n) on the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

Distributing the `clear` task on several threads in not a good idea I think.

The problem, i suppose, is that you have a main thread that calls the `clear` for a long list (it takes time to clear) and gets blocked because the `clear` function doesn't return. In that case maybe it will be good to use a main thread and another thread "garbage collector" that waits until getting the `clear` command and start freeing the memory.

Using 2 threads helps you avoid blocking the caller, Hope i undrestand your question

Comment: Hmmm wait I might be a little confused. Why would the main thread wait for the clear thread to complete? Shouldn't the main thread just start the cleanup thread and just go on about it's business?

Comment: @Hatefiend, the `clear` function is a while loop that calls free over the linked list nodes, so calling `clear` cause the blocking of the caller.

Comment: Yes, but here's the idea: you pass a reference to the `root` `Node` to the cleanup thread. It uses that `Node` to traverse and clear. Meanwhile back in the main thread, you set the `root` property of the `LinkedList` `struct` to `NULL`, that way it's as if the old items in the list are gone forever. You set the `size` of the List to `0` and just like that you've cleared the entire List in `O(1)` speed for the main thread and `O(n)` speed for the cleanup thread. No waiting involved right? Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: @Hatefiend, OK I undrestand and after that what are the problem you are facing ?, I'am thinking about the case after you `clear` your list and start inserting nodes again. In that case If you are using dynamic allocation(malloc) to create your nodes there is no problem because malloc will search a free space and there is no concurency between the space freed and allocated. However if you use static allocation (your list is a static array) than you may face concurency problem when your `clear` thread try to clear a node that your main thread try to allocate, in this case you have to use mutex

Comment: But just a question why you need that is it for learning or you 're facing a real problem ?